# Consuming a WCF service in Postman based on ClientBase

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, postman

I want to test a WCF based on ClientBase class in postman, how should I do that?

Endpoint address="`http://xxxxxxxx/xxxxx/TestService.svc`" and `bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_TESTAPI`"

The Service implementation as below:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName="TESTFApi.TESTAPI")]
public interface TESTAPI {
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/TESTAPI/TESTReceiver", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/TESTAPI/TESTReceiverResponse")]
    string TESTReceiver(string xRequest);
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public interface TESTAPIChannel : TESTAPI, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel {
} 

public partial class TESTIClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<TESTAPI>, TESTAPI {

    public TESTAPIClient() {
    }

    public TESTAPIClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName) {
    }

    public TESTAPIClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public TESTAPIClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public TESTAPIClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress) {
    }

    public string TESTReceiver(string xRequest) {
        return base.Channel.TESTReceiver(xRequest);
    }
}
```

I want to simulate a call in Postman to TESTReceiver(xRequest)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a SOAPAction HTTP header and a standard SOAP envelop to the HTTP request can simply call the WCF service created by BasichttpBinding.
Here is an HTTP request captured by Fiddler.

```
POST http://10.157.13.69:4386/ HTTP/1.1 
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/ITestService/Test"
Host:10.157.13.69:4386
Content-Length: 129
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive  
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><Test xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"/></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Thereby we could construct a request to the WCF based on the TestReceiver interface.
[image]
Request body(Raw).

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body><TestReceiver xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"/></s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

---

One more thing we pay attention to is the default namespace of the service contract is "", which should be replaced with the practical value if you have set up.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.